# Android Constraint Layout Auto Move

Tags: android, layout

Layout Error:

[image: Layout Error]

When I write inside the white balloon, the size of balloon start increase so it's okay. But the overlay the name John Doe, and the text inside blue balloon.

However, I'm stuck and I can't make this responsive.

I create too many layout for testing and nothing. I create some constraints 
 to bottom to white balloon connecting in Text John, but I can't. It is not working.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/chatlayout"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingTop="8dp">


<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/chatlayoutsoon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="200dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:background="@drawable/chat_mensagem_enviada_bg"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/chatlayout"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.97"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/chatlayout"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/chatlayout"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/chatlayout"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">


    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/chatlayoutinterno"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/chat_mensagem_recebida_bg"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.97"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/chatlayoutsoon"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/chatlayoutsoon"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/chatlayoutsoon"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/chatlayoutsoon"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_chat_message2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
            android:maxWidth="240dp"
            android:padding="1dp"
            android:text="adjasdiasdjioasdjoasjdoiajdodsadasdsadadadadsadadasdsadaadadasdadasdasdadjas"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mine_nome_data" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mine_nome_data"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="61dp"
        android:text="John Doe"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/chatlayoutinterno"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/chatlayoutinterno" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/read"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="82dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/sent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_chat_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-123dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="105dp"
        android:maxWidth="240dp"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:text="adjasdiasdjioasdjoasjdoiajdodsadasdsadadadadsadadasdsadaadadasdadasdasd adjasdiasdjioasdjoasjdoiajdodsadasdsadadadadsadadasdsadaadadasdadasdasd adjasdiasdjioasdjoasjdoiajdodsadasdsadadadadsadadasdsadaadadasdadasdasd"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Can you share a sketch of what you want?

Comment: So, it's like the image that i put in the post.

I think, i have to connect the constraints (bottom) for each control. (Text) and balloon.

Comment: I couldn't figure out where "John Doe" and read icon should be.

Comment: i fix the problem man! thanks so much for your help!   how i said before, just connect the constraints  and he will the job !

Comment: Glad you fixed it. I think you can still use just one ConstraintLayout.

Comment: now i have another problem..i create a post for him.